# Scheme define a lambda

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have the following function to compute the sum from `A` to `B` of a function in scheme:

```
(define (SUM summation-function A increment-function B)
  (if (> A B)
      0
      (+ (summation-function A)
         (SUM
           summation-function (increment-function A) increment-function B))))
```

Currently I define two procedures before calling the function, for example:

```
(define (self x) x)     ; do nothing, just sum itself
(define (inc x) (+ x 1)); normal +1 increment
(SUM self 0 inc 5)
```

How instead could I just define the procedure in the call itself, for example:

```
; in pseudocode
(SUM, lambda x: x, 0, lambda x: (+ x 1), 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, we'd use `lambda`s like this:

```
(SUM (lambda (x) x) 0 (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) 5)
```

For the above example in particular, some Scheme interpreters already provide built-in procedures that do precisely what you want and we can simply say:

```
(SUM identity 0 add1 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your definitions like this:

```
(define self 
  (lambda (x) 
    x))

(define inc 
  (lambda (x) 
    (+ x 1)))
```

Now you haves split up creating the variable `self` and `inc` and the lambda syntax that creates a closure. It is EXACTLY the same as what you wrote in your question.

By substitution rules you should be able to replace a variable with the expression in its definition:

```
(SUM self 0 inc 5)

;; is the same as
(SUM (lambda (x) 
        x)
     0
     (lambda (x) 
        (+ x 1))
     5)
```

Please note that older Scheme reports [wasn't case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677474/case-sensitivity-in-scheme-symbols), but `SUM` and `sum` are two different names in later reports. It is also common to use lower space letters for variables and procedure names are, as I showed earlier, variables. This is why the procedure `list` stops working when you define a value to the variable `list`. One namespace to rule them all.